# Wrong data points reporting in Bosun (issue with downsampling)

Tags: opentsdb, bosun

I have a metric that I check over the 2 hours period using the max aggregator (for example 9:30 AM till 11:30 AM PST). Opentsdb UI shows that there was only one data point at 10:16 AM PST. And if I choose 2h max downsampling, then the UI shows one data point at 10:00 AM which is correct. When I check the same metric using Bosun UI for the same time period, the data point is registered at 10:52 AM PST and if I choose 2h max downsampling then I receive "No Results".

I have tried other metrics as well, anytime I use the same value for the downsampling as for the overall query, I receive "No Results" while with reduced downsampling or no downsampling at all, there are data points.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain the Bosun's behavior in this example.

Comment: If you hit Alt-P it should bring up miniprofiler. You can then see the JSON query that is sent to OpenTSDB. I'm wondering what that looks like.

Comment: the query looks legit:

{
  "start": 1459355416,
  "end": 1459362616,
  "queries": [
    {
      "aggregator": "max",
      "metric": "metric.count",
      "rateOptions": {},
      "downsample": "2h-max",
      "filters": [
        {
          "type": "regexp",
          "tagk": "tag1",
          "filter": "value1",
          "groupBy": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Bosun currently is hardcoded to use the UTC timezone for everything. We recommend changing OpenTSDB/HBase to use UTC as well. There are Github issues for making this more apparent [in the UI](https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/issues/1203) or for [changing to a local timezone](https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/issues/680). There was an attempt to add a setting for [changing the timezone](https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/pull/685), but it was not able to be merged.

Stack Overflow uses UTC for all our systems, so we don't have a need to implement support for other timezones. UTC is highly recommended due to issues with daylight savings time and servers in multiple locations, but if someone wants to add local timezone support we are happy to discuss the implementation on Github or in the slack chatroom.

Comment: I have checked that we also use UTC for all our systems